# Is it bad practice to add my own attributes to instances?

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, instance, instance-variables

I am creating a list of subprocesses that takes a URL and a folder path and saves the images on the page at that URL to the folder. When I start each subprocess I set `subprocess.url` and `subprocess.path`. Later in my code I poll the list of subprocesses and remove finished ones, and print to my log file the URL and folder (which I get from the attributes I previously set), and # images in it.

However, I have a feeling this kind of thing is bad practice because this might be overwriting an attribute used by the subprocess class itself. Is this bad? And if yes, what's a better way to keep track of values associated with an instance. Should I create a wrapper class with a subprocess as an attribute?

Comment: It's not best practice, but there is much worse. It might ge an ideato have a simple class with the process and whatever you need additionally as attributes.

Comment: Yes, use another builtin container like a `collections.namedtuple` or even a `dict`. A class is also a good choice.

Comment: If the URL and the path are already separate arguments to the command, you can just extract them from `subprocess.args`; `Popen(["echo", "a", "b"]).args == ["echo", "a", "b"]`.

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but I think your purpose can be better served with `shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, f)` where f is a file handle opened with `wb` flag.

Comment: Okay thanks guys, I will store the jobs as a list of dicts, with each dict having the keys 'url', 'path' and 'subprocess'.

Comment: @Rocky Li Thank you, I'll keep that in mind. But in this case my question was simplified for the sake of posting here. I'm actually doing a bunch of actions for each URL.

Comment: `subprocess` is a module. `subprocess.Popen` is a class, so you could derived a custom subclass from it and add the needed attributes there. You'll still have to be careful to not override existing attributes, although even if you do, it can still made it work.

Answer (score -1):

Here comes handy that `_private_vars` start with a `_`. The public attributes are documented, therefore you know if you overwrite something. If this was not the case than you couldn't do inheritence.

That being said it is not a nice solution, especially if someday sombody else may stumble upon your code. But if it makes a on-time job quick, then do it.

Comment: That's a convention, not something you should count on.